# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ECHO, expecting ',' or ';'

Tags: php, html-table

```
echo '<table class="table" cellspacing="50px">'
       echo '<thead>'
           echo '<tr>'
                echo '<th>'FIRST NAME'</th>'
                echo '<th>'LAST NAME'</th>'
                echo'<th>'DEPARTMENT ID'</th>'
                echo '<th>'EMAIL'</th>'
            echo'</tr>'
        echo'</thead>'
        echo'<tbody>'

                foreach ($output as $outputs){
                echo '<tbody>';
                echo '<tr>';
                echo '<td>'. $outputs["FIRST_NAME"]."</td>";
                echo '<td>'. $outputs["LAST_NAME"]."</td>";
                echo '<td>'. $outputs["DEPARTMENT_ID"]."</td>";
                echo '<td>'. $outputs["EMAIL"]."</td>";
                echo '<tr>';
                echo '</tbody>';
                }

        echo'</tbody>'

    echo'</table>'
```

My table was working just fine in html and then I tried putting it PHP and it is giving an unexpected echo on the thead. I am looking for help on why I'm getting this error Parse error:

> syntax error, unexpected T_ECHO, expecting ',' or ';'

Comment: How about a `;` every statement?

Comment: You can get rid of all the echos below the first one and just `echo '` and end it with `';` or just use [**heredoc**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) or [**nowdoc**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc)

Comment: Consider changing your approach, so that HTML is rendered outside of PHP mode, and PHP is just used for dynamic stuff. See [an example here](https://github.com/halfer/php-tutorial-project/blob/rebase4/list-posts.php).

Answer (score 2):

- You missed `;` in several lines
- And this line `echo '<th>'FIRST NAME'</th>'` missed to escape the "single quotes", to fix escape the "quotes" like this: `echo '<th>\'FIRST NAME\'</th>';`

Read more in: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Fix using like this:

```
echo '<table class="table" cellspacing="50px">';
       echo '<thead>';
           echo '<tr>';
                echo '<th>\'FIRST NAME\'</th>';
                echo '<th>\'LAST NAME\'</th>';
                echo '<th>\'DEPARTMENT ID\'</th>';
                echo '<th>\'EMAIL\'</th>';
            echo '</tr>';
        echo '</thead>';
        echo '<tbody>';
```

And:

```
    echo '</tbody>';

echo '</table>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Every single `echo` you have needs to end with a `;`.

For example, on the first line:

```
echo '<table class="table" cellspacing="50px">';
```

This is referred to in PHP as [instruction separation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.instruction-separation.php).

You also missed some spaces between `echo` and the strings being `echo`ed...and you have nested `<tbody>` tags...

Comment: thank you, i forgot to add those